# Using reflection to find propert name and value and associated mapping

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

I have a class

```
public Class Test

{
  public string text1 {get;set;}
  public string Text2 {get;set;}
}

var Testobj = new Test();

Testobj.text1 = "col1";
Testobj.Text2 = "col2";
```

Now I have another class

```
public Class TestRel
{

   public string col1 {get;set;}

   public string col2 {get;set;}
}


var Realobj = new TestRel()

Realobj.col1 = "hi";
Realobj.col2 = "hello";
```

So you see here Class Test is holding the property values for class TestRel. Now through reflection, I am trying to find the property name and value of class "Test"

Once I have the value of properties of  class "Test" Then I can use it to find the value of col1 and col2 from class TestRel all via reflection.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Well you'd use the reflection APIs, which are fairly well documented... please show what you've tried so far, and what went wrong.

Comment: The scenario here is unclear.   Please update your question and include an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
Test Testobj = new Test();
// Find the fields for Testobj.
Type myType = typeof(Test);
FieldInfo[] fields = myType.GetFields();
for(int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
{
    // Get value for field.
    var myValue = fields[i].GetValue(Testobj);
}
```

[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)